# Global variable with private-attribute

Tags: php, oop, variables

I have the following class:

```
class validationHandler{
    private $dataType; //set via constructor ...
    private $validation = null;

    private function requireValidation(){
        if($this->validation == null){
              $this->validation = loadDataFromJSONfile($this->dataType);
        }
    }

    public function validate($data){
        $this->requireValidation();
        //validate... the rules are in the $validation-variable
    }
}
```

When an object needs to validate some data, it makes a new validation-object and calls validate().

The first time something needs to be validated, the data is loaded from a json-file.

But: Sometimes I have several Objects which need the same validation-file. And This code loads the file for each Object.

**Question:** Is there a way to set $validation global, so that every object accesses the same variable, but without loosing the private-property?

(Notice that I have different validation-files and different kinds of objects. An objects tells the validationHanlder in __construct() which type it has, and which validation-file should be loaded. So I need $validation to be an array. *(Didn't write it in the code, so it's more readable)*

Comment: Extract the validation into a separate class. Inject an instance of that class into all objects that need this validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create your variable using [`static`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php), it sounds like.